# Why does the Python community not close questions about ImportError?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

My primary concern is the `ImportError` questions which I have witnessed to be coming at a pretty high rate.

Almost all forms of Python `ImportError` question I have seen have a single problem and the answer to that problem has to be repeated over and over again (check your `sys.path` etc).

For those who are doubtful can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20ImportError).

There could be other questions that could be of the same ilk.

So why does the Python community not close questions they should really close?

The way these questions are allowed to pass (adding noise) is worrying.

Comment: Too many of them use up all of the close votes of the people who care?

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the problem is that there are no canonical "How to diagnose ImportError: blah blah blah?" answers that could be pointed to. There are a few questions that *could* be turned to this purpose:

- [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named)
- [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)
- [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)

...but all of them are to some extent fixated on the specific problems of the folks who asked them, rather than laying out a standard "how to diagnose and fix" workflow. This leads to a couple of problems:

- It's harder for folks searching for a solution to find one that appears to be applicable to their case, leading to them asking *yet another* question.
- It's harder for folks searching for a canonical question to point potential duplicates at to find one that's obviously applicable, thus leading them to just answer rather than closing.

I recommend taking one or more of the topics above and fleshing it out into a full-on guide to diagnosing these errors, in the style of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) or [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

See also: [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)